# Getting all wall posts and comments using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook, comments, posts, restfb

At first: I know there were some similar topics and I wrote some code according to them (as seeing below). I'm new in Facebook api so I'm a little bit lost :D
Anyway, my app has to get all wall posts and comments but I'm not able to get it all. Could anyone help me please? Here are my methods:

```
public static void getFacebookPosts(String url){            
            try{
                  LoggedFacebookClient client = new LoggedFacebookClient();

                  Page page = client.fetchObject(url, Page.class);  
                  System.out.println(page.getName());
                  Connection<Post> pageFeed = client.fetchConnection(page.getId() + "/feed", Post.class);

            //Getting posts:
                  for (List<Post> feed : pageFeed){
                        for (Post post : feed){     
                             //PRINTING THE POST 
                             getAllPostComments(post.getId(), client);
                        }
                   }
            }catch(com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException ex){
                  System.out.println("\n!!!!!!! Token Expired !!!!!!!!\n");
            }
}

private static void getAllPostComments(String postId, DefaultFacebookClient client){
            int currentCount = 0;
            JsonObject jsonObject = client.fetchObject(postId + "/comments", JsonObject.class, 
                  Parameter.with("summary", true), Parameter.with("limit", 1));
            long commentsTotalCount = jsonObject.getJsonObject("summary").getLong("total_count");

            System.out.println("\nComments:");
            boolean pom = true;
            while(pom == true){       //There should be "while(currentCount < commentsTotalCount)" but currentCount is always < then commentsTotalCount. That's the problem :)
                  pom = false;
                  Connection<Comment> comments = client.fetchConnection(postId + "/comments", 
                        Comment.class, Parameter.with("limit", 50000), Parameter.with("offset", currentCount));

                  for(Comment komentar : comments.getData()){
                        pom = true;
                        currentCount++;
                        stazenychKomentu++;
                        String mess = komentar.getMessage().replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll("\r", " ");
                        System.out.println("    [" + currentCount + "]: " + komentar.getFrom().getName() + " ## " + mess);
                  }
            }
            celkemKomentu += commentsTotalCount;
            System.out.println(currentCount + " / " + commentsTotalCount);
}
```

and here is the way I get the acces token:

```
public LoggedFacebookClient(){
       super();
       AccessToken accessToken = this.obtainAppAccessToken(API_KEY, APP_SECRET);
       this.accessToken = accessToken.getAccessToken();
}
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me. Thanks a lot and sorry if my English isn't perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all posts you just need to make this:

```
    while (pageFeed.hasNext()) {
    pageFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnectionPage(pageFeed.getNextPageUrl(),Post.class);
    }
```

Parameter.with("limit", xxx)  work for less then 200 posts. And don't forget about long-live access token!

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens

Comment: so it's not possible to receive more than 200 posts. or to be more precise, posts that are older than the last 200?